# C#11 `IParsable<TSelf>` signature

Tags: c#, interface, c#-11.0

I've started playing with the new interfaces in C#11 with `static abstract` methods. One thing I don't get is the need for the generic constraint in `IParsable<TSelf>`, which is defined as:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Defines a mechanism for parsing a string to a value.
//
// Type parameters:
//   TSelf:
//     The type that implements this interface.
public interface IParsable<TSelf> where TSelf : IParsable<TSelf>?
{
    static abstract TSelf Parse(string s, IFormatProvider? provider);

    static abstract bool TryParse([NotNullWhen(true)] string? s,
      IFormatProvider? provider, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out TSelf result);
}
```

why not just

```
public interface IParsable<TSelf>
{
    static abstract TSelf Parse(string s, IFormatProvider? provider);

    static abstract bool TryParse([NotNullWhen(true)] string? s, 
      IFormatProvider? provider, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out TSelf result);
}
```

I understand the latter would allow things like:

```
class MyInt : IParsable<int>
{
  public static abstract int Parse(string s, IFormatProvider? provider)
  {...}

  ...
}
```

which is not the way the interface is supposed to be implemented, the class type and `TSelf` should be the same. But the former allows `TSelf` to be any type implementing `IParsable<TSelf>` which includes other types than `int`.

Also, wouldn't it have been possible to introduce a new `TSelf` keyword representing the type of the class implementing the interface (I think Delphi had such a thing with `ClassType`)?

Comment: @GuruStron I does, thanks. For some reason `IParseable` was renamed `IParsable` which made my search for similar posts fail. I think a `TSelf` keyword representing the class/struct implementing the interface would have helped in this case but there are probably good reasons why it was designed that way.

Comment: More on that topic on Stephen Cleary's blog: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2022/09/modern-csharp-techniques-1-curiously-recurring-generic-pattern.html